# Problem in installing Qiskit

Tags: programming, qiskit

When I try to install Qiskit using Pip install Qiskit I get the error as shown in the attached snapshot.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

[image: Qiskit install error]

Comment: This might be a better question for StackOverflow; in this case, install the BLAS library and export the path (included in the error message)

Comment: Hi. Welcome to Quantum Computing SE! Please [do not post images of texts you want to quote](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052), but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use [MathJax](https://quantumcomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/49) instead. Review [Why are images of text, code, and mathematical expressions discouraged?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/320052).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue is within the `pyscf` package that is required by qiskit. It says [here](https://sunqm.github.io/pyscf/install.html) that this error may occur with certain versions of python, and I have seen it commonly coming up with python 3.8. There are some workarounds in that link, but if you have nothing forcing you to use python 3.8, I would suggest downgrading to the next newest version before that.

I have been running on python 3.7.5 (which you should be able to install by simply specifying `python=3.7` when creating a new anaconda environment) and I do not see this error.

Comment: Many Thanks to you. I have been able to install qiskit. I am following the first example on qiskit.org. Now the problem is when I run the code , I am not able to see the circuit and histogram. The thing is the commands circuit.draw() and plot_histogram() are not working. I have also installed the terra visualizations.  If you can provide solution to this also I will be highly thankful to you.

Comment: This may be better to create a separate question for, as it would be easier for us to see the code and the error/output you are receiving. It also may be different depending on if you are running through a Jupyter Notebook or through the terminal.

My immediate suggestions would be to make to try `print(circuit)` and see if you get any output, and to also make sure `plot_histogram()` is being imported from the correct module. If you aren't receiving an error at all, you can try saving the output from `plot_histogram()` and see if you can see anything that way